# XPATH FACEBOOK How can i get xpath or css selector ? - selenium/java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, css

I automated some facebook functions for pratice selenium, but i can't click on search options.

How can i try this ?

Search:

[image]

elements: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
String option = "esporte interativo";
String locator = "//ul[@id='facebar_typeahead_view_list']" + 
                  "/li[contains(normalize-space(.), '" + option +"')]";

driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).click();
```